# List of branches in GitSCM checkout step?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-git-plugin

I started investigating the GitSCM class in Jenkins, so I see the parameters it takes in the constructor.
There's only one thing I don't understand:
The `branches` parameter is of type: `List<BranchSpec> branches`.

My question is: why does it take a list of branches? why would I checkout a list of branches in the `checkout` step?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the banches you want to checkout. These are the branches you want to build.

In [jenkins.io documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) it says:

> Specify the branches if you'd like to track a specific branch in a
> repository. If left blank, all branches will be examined for changes
> and built.

So if you just want master and feature1 branch tracked, use `refs/heads/master, refs/heads/feature1` or let it blank for building all branches.

Comment: What do you mean by "These are branches you want to build"? What is to "build a branch" if not checking out the branch and then build the code in it?

Comment: It will just check for the branches you list here, the rest will not be checked out nor built. If you need all, just keep it empty.